# Use templated struct as template parameter to static constexpr member

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to set up a `static constexpr` member of a template struct to be assigned by a template parameter, which in itself is a template struct. For example:

```
template<int f>
struct Column
{
    static constexpr int flags = f;
};

template<Column<int> c> // Error: Template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
struct Row
{
    static constexpr Column<int> column = c; // Error: Template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
};
```

This is to be used to create other structs with information, for example:

```
struct Table
{
    static constexpr Column<5> myCol();
    static constexpr Row<myCol> myRow(); // Error: Value of type 'Column<5> ()' is not implicitly convertible to 'int'
};
```

Xcode gives me the errors as described in the comments. I think the idea as to what I want to achieve should be fairly clear, but how can I implement it correctly? I want the template parameter for `Column<int>` to be generic (i.e. not using `Column<5>` for example) so that any generated instances of `Column<int>` can be used as template argument to `Row`.

**Edit: more context to better handle the XY problem:**

I am creating templated structs that will represent SQLite columns. These template structs will have column name, flags, default values and so on. This is the `Foo` class above, in very simple terms.

Then I will create similar structs for SQLite rows. These structs need to know about which column they belong to to know which flags it has (`NOT NULL`, `PRIMARY KEY` and similar things), which default value it has if any, and so on. Therefore I want to pass the column struct (i.e. `Foo<int>`) as a template argument to the row struct (`Bar` in the example above).

Comment: pass foo and integer, then instantiate foo in bar? Also looks like XY problem.

Comment: should `Bar` be only used with `Foo`?

Comment: Yes, `Bar` should only be instantiated by `Foo`, _but_ `Foo` might get more template parameters than in the example, though this should not matter.

Comment: @Incomputable Could you show how to do what you suggest? Also thanks for commenting on the XY problem - I hadn't heard about that before. Interesting "fallacy". For the interested: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Krøllebølle, I'm sure that now it will solve the problem, though not in the best way.

Answer (score 1):

### std::integral_constant

Lets see an example:

```
template <std::size_t index>
class column: public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, index>
{
    ...
};
```

Then, when passing to row, or vice versa, use this:

```
template <std::size_t column_index>
class row 
{
    ...
};
```

Now, lets use it:

```
row<column<1>{}> myrow;
```

Notice the `{}`, it will create an instance of `column`, but it will automatically decay to `std::size_t`!

---

The problem is that people still can use it directly with the index, so you might want to put a clang-tidy check in your codebase for this.

---

### Template metaprogramming

One can also use partial specializations.

```
template <typename column_t>
class row;

template <std::size_t column_index>
class row<column<column_index>>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this what you were searching for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
template<int f>
struct Column
{
    static constexpr int flags = f;
};

template<int i>
struct Row
{
    static constexpr Column<i> col;
};
```

`Column<int>` is a non-sensical type, since it passes `int` to a template that is expecting a value of type `int` as its argument.